# 6502 from ODP.NET on a function returning string

Tags: oracle, odp.net, executenonquery, ora-06502

I have a SQL function defined as such:

```
create or replace function func_cmap_unit_test 
(what varchar2)
return varchar2 as 
begin
   return 'hello ' || what || '!';
end func_cmap_unit_test;
```

I tested in SQL Developer and it works fine:

```
select portal_ops.func_cmap_unit_test('world') from dual;
```

I have the following C# code:

```cs
Command.CommandText = funcName;
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Command.Parameters.Add(
    new OracleParameter
    (
        "Output"
        , TypeMapping[typeof(T)]
        //, OracleDbType.Clob
        , ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    )
);

foreach ((string name, object value) param in spParams)
{
    Command.Parameters.Add(param.name, param.value);
}
    if (Command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    Command.Connection.Open();
}
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (T)Command.Parameters[0].Value;
```

The problem is that `Command.ExecuteNonQuery` keeps failing with

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

As you see in the commented code, when I switched the `OracleDbType` to `Clob`, the `ExecuteNonQuery` passed.  I am perplexed why it wouldn't work for `OracleDBType`.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You return a `VARCHAR2`, then the parameter type should be also `OracleDbType.Varchar2` rather than `OracleDbType.Clob`

Comment: I think for `OracleDbType.Varchar2` return value you have to specify the `Size` (i.e. length) property of the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, below code shows what you need. For output type of parameters of string types you need to provide size, otherwise it will be `1`. Remember, that Parameter return value will be `OracleString`. You can check `IsNull` property on it

```cs
string retval = null;
using (var conn = new OracleConnection("conn str . . .")
{
    using (var cmd= new OracleCommand(funcName, conn)
    {
        cmd = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var p = new OracleParameter("out", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        foreach ((string name, object value) param in spParams)
        {
            Command.Parameters.Add(param.name, param.value);
        }

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        retval = cmd.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```